# How to vectorize newline \n in tensorflow textVectorization layer?

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings, vector-space-models

I am working on text generation model and i want to vectorize the newline character '\n' as  a word in tensorflow. How DO i do it.

I have done this so far. but tensorflow just not consider it.

- cleaning

```
import re
def clean(x):
    x = str(x).lower()
    x = x.replace('\r\n\r\n','\n')
    x = x.replace('\r\n','\n')
    x = x.replace('\n', ' \n ')
    # x = x.replace('  ',' ')
    x = re.sub("[^\r\n?.!:a-zA-Z]", " ", x) # removing punctuation
    x = x.replace('!',' ! ')
    x = x.replace(':',' : ')
    x = x.replace('.',' . ')
    x = x.replace('?',' ? ')
    return x
```

- Initialized vectorization layer

```
vector = layers.TextVectorization(max_tokens=max_token+2, standardize=None, pad_to_max_tokens=False,)
vector.adapt(william['content'])
```

- cleaned it

```
a = ['how are you ?', 'who are you? \n let go', ' some word. \n other word']
print('a: ',a)
clean_a = list(map(lambda x: clean(x),a))
print('clean a: ',clean_a)
a_vec = vector(clean_a) # vectorizer sttips punctuations
print('vectorized: ',a_vec)
print(a_vec.numpy())
# print('vector to text: ')
for i in a_vec:
    print(idtotext(i.numpy()))
```

output:

```
a:  ['how are you ?', 'who are you? \n let go', ' some word. \n other word']
clean a:  ['how are you  ? ', 'who are you ?   \n  let go', ' some word .   \n  other word']

vectorized:  tf.Tensor(
[[149  49  28  38   0   0]
 [ 74  49  28  38  62 273]
 [208 398   4 257 398   0]], shape=(3, 6), dtype=int64)

back to text: 
how are you ?  
who are you ? let go
some word . other word
```

Please tell me how to i vectorize newline character?

Comment: Have you tried the function tf.convert_to_tensor(in_string) and then vectorizer = TextVectorization(), out_tensor = vectorizer(in_tensor)?

Comment: I have the same problem, i looked at the source code but i can spot why the TextVectorization layer 'swallows' newlines. I will now try it with a given vocabulary... or i skip this thing altogether!

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at the tokens that are used during the vectorization? Maybe the '\n' character is not considered as a token. Thus it is not vectorized. That is why while trying to get back to the initial text from the vectorized form it doesn't appear.